# System.TypeLoadException:Could not load type 'System.MathF' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm brand new to C#, and more specifically, I'm working with Unity. I've been trying to test the MathF library in a C# program I created on WSL2, but am stuck with the error message given by the title of this issue. I tried googling the error message, but nothing specific came up for 'System.MathF'. Instead, I found a lot of explanations regarding the "System.TypeLoadException", but again, nothing specific to the 'System.MathF'. Finally, I found one topic that was questioning the difference between Unity's MathF library and the C# Math library.

This leads me to question - does MathF exist for C# outside of Unity? Perhaps that is the reason for the error message?

Comment: There is a `System.MathF` class in .NET Core 2.0 and later and .NET Standard 2.1. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=net-7.0) says that it is declared in the System.Runtime.dll library from .NET 5 and System.Runtime.Extensions.dll before that. If you're targeting .NET Framework then it is presumably not available. Not sure whether Unity uses a different version of mscorlib.dll that does include that class. If not, not sure why it's trying to load from that assembly.